# Regex - Match only string with certain word

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a problem with a regex expression in a Python 3 script:

A variable has the following content:

```
<p class="paragraphClass" id="firstParagraph"><span class="spanClass" id="firstSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus massa et justo aliquam consequat.</span></p><p class="paragraphClass" id="secondParagraph"><span class="spanClass" id="secondSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus massa et justo aliquam consequat.</span></p><p class="paragraphClass" id="thirdParagraph"><span class="spanClass">##START_ACT##</span></p><p class="paragraphClass" id="firstParagraph"><span class="spanClass" id="firstSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam faucibus massa et justo aliquam consequat.</span></p>
```

I want to get:

```
<p class="paragraphClass" id="thirdParagraph"><span class="spanClass">##START_ACT##</span></p>
```

but I have to search through the string `##START_ACT##`

I don't know the length of the other strings, the name of the class or id, so I cannot trust regular expressions such as:

```
<p.{0,80}##START_ACT##.*?</p>
```

Can this be done with a regex?

Comment: You really want to get literally `##START_ACT##`? If not, can you be more specific what you want as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:
`r".*(<p.*?##START_ACT##.*?/p>).*"`

It will match the whole text, but the group will contain only what you need.